# WSO2 Complex Event Processor

Tags: queue, jms, wso2, complex-event-processing

I have a little problem with WSO2 CEP. I'm using version 3.1.0 and I have a JMS queue.
So, in my queue I have a few different type of events and in CEP I have the same number of different execution plans. My question is about, how can I distinguish incomming events, because now only one execution plan works fine and it get all type of events (so I get a lot of erros, because only one event works with this plan and other doesn't). Is this possible to do, what i'm doing?
Maybe someone had this problem before and could answer me.

Kacu

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid whether your usecase can be achieved because in CEP each event builder is tightly coupled with event stream (event stream contains a strict format). Since event builder gets the events from a specific queue/topic it is not possible to handle different type of event formats.

I can propose two solutions here,

1) Without using a queue, use a topic then create event builders for each event type, but here you may need to write siddhi query to avoid duplicated events.

2) Or sending different event formats to different queue if possible..

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem.
I'm trying to avoid the problem with a huge json-mapping (event builder) and filtering in siddhi query (event processor).

```
from <StreamName>(<eventType> contains 'eventTypeName')
Select <event>, <event> ...
```

Regards,
Artur